# Enter Missing Year Amounts with Zeros After GroupBy in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am grouping the following rows.

```
df = df.groupby(['id','year']).sum().sort(ascending=False)

print df

                      amount
id      year        

1       2009             120
        2008             240
        2007             240
        2006             240
        2005             240
2       2014             100
        2013              50
        2012              50
        2011             100
        2010              50
        2006             100
...                      ...
```

Is there a way to add years that do not have any values with the amount equal to zero until a specific year, in this case 2005, as I am showing below?

Expected Output:

```
                      amount
id      year        
        2015               0
        2014               0
        2013               0
        2012               0
        2011               0
        2010               0
        2009             120
        2008             240
        2007             240
        2006             240
        2005             240
2       2015               0
        2014             100
        2013              50
        2012              50
        2011             100
        2010              50
        2009               0
        2008               0
        2007               0
        2006             100
        2005               0
...                      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your first DataFrame, this will add all years that occur with some id to all ids.

`df = df.unstack().fillna(0).stack()`

e.g.

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
         amt
id year     
1  2001    1
   2002    2
   2003    3
2  2002    4
   2003    5
   2004    6

In [17]: df = df.unstack().fillna(0).stack()

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
         amt
id year     
1  2001    1
   2002    2
   2003    3
   2004    0
2  2001    0
   2002    4
   2003    5
   2004    6
```